# Step By Step sample/tutoral to integrate GWT with Spring

Tags: gwt-rpc

Is there any tutorial or sample code available with detailed explanation on "How to integrate GWT with Spring MVC.

Thanks,
Vishal Anand.

Answer (score 0):

http://technophiliac.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/giving-gwt-a-spring-in-its-step/